# Reducer outputting value for two different keys in same file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

Hi I have written a mapreduce job which is generically parsing XML file. I am able to parse an XML file and getting all key value pair generated properly.I am having 6 different keys and there corresponding values. So I am running 6 different reducers in parallel.

Now problem I am facing is reducer is putting two different key - value pair in same file and remaining 4 key-value in individual files. So in short out of 6 files in output from reducer I am getting 4 files with single-key value pair and 1 file with two key-value pair and 1 file having nothing.

I tried doing research on Google and various forums only thing I concluded is I need a partitioner to solve this problem. I am new hadoop and so can someone put some light on this issue and help me solve this.

I am working on a pseudo-node cluster and using Java as a programming language. I am not able to share code here but still try to describe problem in brief.

Let me know more information is needed and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did my answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

Having only 6 keys for 6 reducers isn't the best utilisation of hadoop - while it would be nice for each of the 6 to go to a separate reducer it isn't guaranteed.

Keys cannot get split across reducers, so if you were to have less than 6 keys only a subset of your reducers would have any work to do. You should consider rethinking your key assignment (and perhaps input files' appropriate-ness for hadoop) and perhaps use a system such that there are enough keys to be spread somewhat evenly amongst the reducers.

EDIT: I believe what you might be after is [`MultipleOutputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html), which has the method [`generateFileNameForKeyValue(key, value, name)`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html#generateFileNameForKeyValue%28K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29), allowing you to generate a file to write out to per key rather than just one file per `Reducer`.

Comment: Yes can you please elaborate. I think you interpreted question in a wrong way. I am outputting from mapper different keys uniquely but I want them each key and its corresponding values in a separate files. For this I am having n number of reducers. But problem is reducer is outputting two different keys and there corresponding values in a single file. If you can reply your answer keeping this issue in mind that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop by default uses a default [Hash partitioner  - click here](http://cornercases.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/an-example-configurable-partitioner/), which is something like

```
public class HashPartitioner<K2, V2> implements Partitioner<K2, V2> {

  public void configure(JobConf job) {}

  /** Use {@link Object#hashCode()} to partition. */
  public int getPartition(K2 key, V2 value,
                          int numReduceTasks) {
    return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
  }

}
```

The key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks will return a number between 0 to numReduceTasks and in your case the range would be 0 to 5, since, numRuduceTask=6

The catch is there in that line itself - two such statement may return you the same number.
And, as a result two different keys could go to the same reducer.
    For e.g.-

```
("go".hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % 6
```

will return you 4 and,

```
("hello".hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % 6
```

will also return you 4.

So, what I would suggest here is that if you want to be sure that all your 6 keys get processed by 6 different reducers, you need to create your own partitioner to get what you desire.

Check out [this link](http://cornercases.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/an-example-configurable-partitioner/) for creating a custom partitioner, if you have any confusion and you specify your custom partitioner something like the following using the Job class.

`job.setPartitioner(<YourPartionerHere.class>);`

Hope this helps.